# The sound jerk when playing video

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, android-video-player

I am building an app using AndroidFFmpeg  https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg.

While playing the first video, the sound is well. But for the next video, the sound jerk.

Maybe the issue relate to memory issue, but I can't find anything.

Anyone know this issue, please help me. Any suggestion would be appreciated, thanks!